# Drupal 7 Media Gallery Extra stopped working

Tags: php, drupal-7

I am using such modules as **Media**, **Media Gallery** and **Media Gallery Extra** (with *Media Gallery Directory* inside) in my **Drupal 7** for creating of galleries. Straight after installing everything worked perfectly. There was created about 10 galleries, media was successfully uploaded in different directories (*sites/default/files/galleries/NAME_OF_THE_GALLERY/...*).

After few days (I haven't tracked the reason unfortunately) the functionality of the module has stopped operating: all the media created via Media Gallery were uploading into the **default path** (*sites/default/files/*). The same result is on the server under Ubuntu and local copy under Windows (so I guess there are no problem with file/dir permissions).

The configuration of the module is still the same. The module files have not been changed. Disabling/enabling of the module doesn't fix the problem. It **only** can be fixed by **re-installing** of the media_gallery_directory, media_gallery_extra and media_gallery modules. But in this case all the media files/comments/galleries are **removed**. So this is not my option if to take into account that there are already about 150 galleries have been uploaded to a production site.

I've tried to manipulate with some db config fields on my development environment - but everything is unsuccessfully.

How can I fix this issue? Any comments are deeply appreciated.